# Macros to run in all workbooks

Tags: excel, binaryfiles, vba

I am currently attempting to create several separate macros that will run in all workbooks.  I have read several posts that are leading me towards either a binary excel document or a personal document.  The first macro I am trying to do is a very simple vlookup replace.

```
Sub countryLookup()
Dim CLookUp As Range
Dim CActive As Range

Set CLookUp = Workbooks("Floating_Macro.xlsb").Worksheets(1).Range("A:B")
Set CActive = ActiveWorkbook.Selection

For Each cell In CActive
    On Error Resume Next

    cell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell.Value, CLookUp, 2, 0)
Next cell    
End Sub
```

I want this to be in any worksheet I open; so that the user highlights the column, and the macro will replace every value with the value from the vlookup.  I'd also like to be able to save these macros with a keyboard shortcut.  When I close out of the Floating_Macro.xlsb document that contains this code, the macro no longer shows up in other workbooks.  Do I need to put the lookup table in the code rather than in a tab in the .xlsb?  Thanks in advance and let me know if I need to clarify further.

Comment: Do you just have it open, or do you have it registered as an add-in?

Comment: I would like for the macros to be in any workbook.  The .xlsb that has the macro should never have to be opened, ideally.  I may be going the wrong direction with the binary document.

Comment: Put it in `C:\Users\{you}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Addins`. Then go to Developer -> Add-Ins in Excel and check the box next to it.

Comment: I am getting C:\Users\{you}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Addins\PERONAL.xlsb is not a valid add in

Comment: Try saving it as an .xlam file instead. Same location.

Comment: @Comintern, I ended up just recording a macro & saving in PERSONAL.xlsb to create it.  Everythings working now, thanks for the help.